# How to place text object successfully under an image/polygon object with jsxgraph 0.99.7?

Tags: layer, jsxgraph

I would like to simply place a text object under an image object I created using jsxgraph.

- Tried setting for the text object layer:2 and the image object layer:7.
- Tried setting board.options.layer.text=2, then created the text object, then set board.options.layer.text=9 again.

The object does give the correct layer value when investigating, however it does not visually do this. This works well for non text objects. Would this a text related bug?

Answer (score 0):

JSXGraph distinguishes two types of texts: `display:'html'` and `display:'internal'`. The former type of text element uses an HTML tag and is always strictly "above" any JSXGraph construction (and thus ignores the layer structur). The latter type of text element obeys the layer structure. The default is `display:'html'`.
Here is an example (https://jsfiddle.net/8xms49pu/2/):

```
var circ = board.create('circle', [[0, 0], 3], 
                {fillColor: 'yellow', fillOpacity: 0.8});
var txt1 = board.create('text', [1, 1, 'HTML'], {layer: 1});
var txt1 = board.create('text', [-3.2, -1, 'internal'], 
                {layer: 1, display: 'internal'});
```

Images can be put into layers. This means, one also has to use `display:'internal'`. Here is an example (https://jsfiddle.net/jdw7z1nq/1/):

```
var im = board.create('image', ['https://jsxgraph.org/wp/img/logo_tw.png', [-3, -3], [6, 6]], 
            {layer: 10});
var circ = board.create('circle', [[0,0], 3], 
            {fillColor: 'yellow', layer: 6});
var txt = board.create('text', [1, 1, 'Hello'], 
            {layer: 5, display: 'internal'});
```

The advantage of HTML texts is that they can contain any kind HTML content, for example MathJax or form tags or images, ... So, you might also consider putting the image into a text element.

Comment: Thanks Alfred for the nice reply - also I appreciate your time.
I have found this has worked for me - the text does go below other objects. It doesn't work too well when you wish to use other content but it does work otherwise. So you can place images _into_ text elements, you say?